# How do I order documents by the number of elements in an array that match a query?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a collection in mongo in which each document contains an array of timestamps, and I need to find (aggregate) the documents with the most timestamps in a given time frame.

I know that I need to use $aggregate, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to filter & count the number of elements in array.

An example document looks like this:

```
{
"_id" : "en.m.wikipedia.org",
"times" : [
    ISODate("2019-06-03T14:19:33.405Z"),
    ISODate("2019-06-03T14:19:52.394Z"),
    ISODate("2019-06-03T14:29:15.474Z"),
    ISODate("2019-06-03T14:29:30.768Z"),
    ISODate("2019-06-03T14:30:25.578Z"),
    ISODate("2019-06-03T15:00:22.493Z"),
    ISODate("2019-06-03T15:05:03.759Z"),
    ISODate("2019-06-03T15:18:05.677Z"),
    ISODate("2019-06-03T15:38:22.771Z"),
    ISODate("2019-06-03T15:44:51.025Z"),
    ISODate("2019-06-03T15:45:15.336Z"),
    ISODate("2019-06-03T15:49:06.227Z"),
    ISODate("2019-06-03T17:10:19.396Z"),
    ISODate("2019-06-03T18:02:37.093Z"),
    ISODate("2019-06-03T18:39:29.812Z"),
    ISODate("2019-06-03T19:06:49.310Z"),
    ISODate("2019-06-03T19:46:52.381Z"),
    ISODate("2019-06-03T20:16:45.675Z"),
],
"source" : ["Admin"]
}
```

Ideal output would be something like this, with the count only showing the number of timestamps within the given time period:

```
[
    {_id: "en.m.wikipedia.org", count: 12},
    {_id: "facebook.com", count: 7},
    etc...
]
```

Answer (score 1):

According to my understanding,

I have devised the below solution,

```
db.wikidata.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$times"
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "times": {
                $gte: ISODate("2019-06-03T14:30:25.578Z"),
                $lte: ISODate("2019-06-03T19:46:52.381Z")
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "count": {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Output:

```
{ "_id" : "en.m.wikipedia.org", "count" : 13 }
```

Now let me explain the mongo query,

```
{
        $unwind: "$times"
}
```

This creates a document corresponding to each value in the "times" array.
This will be used to match our documents within the given time window.

```
{
        $match: {
            "times": {
                $gte: ISODate("2019-06-03T14:30:25.578Z"),
                $lte: ISODate("2019-06-03T19:46:52.381Z")
            }
        }
}
```

The above condition filters the documents based on the given time window.
You can generate ISO dates in javascript and update it to set your own limit.

```
{
        $group: {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "count": {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
}
```

This groups your documents based on the "id" field.

**Note:** I have used an arbitrary name for the collection.